# About paper "Deep Unsupervised Learning using Nonequilibrium Thermodynamics"

Tags: machine-learning, probability, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process

Here is the [paper link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03585) related to the question from my title.

In Appendix B, it computes the entropy of  $p(X^T)$ and says "By design, the cross entropy to $\pi(x^t)$ is constant under our diffusion kernels, and equal to the entropy of $p(x^T)$

I don't quite understand this. Why is the cross entropy constant for all $t$? If this is an assumption, is that well-defined?

Also I do not understand the last sentence in B.2 :where we again used the fact that by design $-\int d \mathbf{x}^{(t)} q\left(\mathbf{x}^{(t)}\right) \log \pi\left(\mathbf{x}^{(t)}\right)=H_p\left(\mathbf{X}^{(T)}\right) \text { is a constant for all } t \text {. }$

Comment: It would help to link the paper and perhaps provide some context behind the quote if possible to give answerers an informed response to your query.

Comment: I just added the link, thanks for your comments

Comment: Please paste in whatever context is necessary to 
understand & answer your question. We want this thread to 
remain valuable even if the link goes dead.